# How validates a database of SQL SERVER CE for WP7 in a C # application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

How verify the State of the database in WP7 if we do not have access to engine?

Essentially, what is the Phone equivalent of this code:

```
public void VerificarFileBD()
{
    try 
    {
        var engine = new SqlCeEngine("Data Source = AdventureWorks.sdf");

        if (false == engine.Verify())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Database is corrupted.");
            engine.Repair(null, RepairOption.RecoverCorruptedRows);
        }   
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API to do this on Windows Phone